# How to calculate multiple average in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

In the case,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x=np.linspace(0,1,100)
y=x**2

result=np.average(y)
print(result)
```

I need to calculate two sets of average as

```
if y>.5 :
    result1=np.average(y=.5)
    result2.np.average(y-.5)
if y<=.5
    result1=np.average(y)
```

`result1` has a maximum `y` value, and `result2` a minimum. However, I cannot apply the `if` condition for a numpy array.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @ninesalt Calculate the average values for the range where y is below or above .5

Comment: Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of your `if` statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine which elements are greater or less than `0.5`, then use that to index back into `y`

```
>>> np.average(y[y>0.5])
0.7443118049178656
>>> np.average(y[y<0.5])
0.16784001632486484
```